# Callback method called often to forward event to Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-java2

So I have this listener on a custom slider view. The view calls `onSliderChanged(int percent)` when the user is sliding the slider. I'm trying to make a network call when the slider changes, but I don't want to make a million network calls since the method is called often when sliding. How can I make this listener callback into an Observable? I know once its an observable I can use debounce and only update after a certain time interval.

I tried doing `Observable.create()` but I'm in a callback method and I can't figure out how that would work. I'm using Kotlin and RxJava2 btw.

```
override fun onSliderChanged(percent: Int)
{
    // Either here or in the presenter I want to make this 
    // callback reactive so I can debounce the callback
    presenter.onSliderChanged(percent)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear from your question exactly how you pass your listener, but there are two general cases that come to mind. Pick the one matches your implementation.

**Case 1:  The listener is passed as an interface**

For this, I assume you have an interface similar too --

```
interface SliderChangedListener {
    fun onSliderChanged(percent: Int)
}
```

and a method in your `Slider` class that takes an instance of that listener --

```
fun setSlideListener(listener: SliderChangedListener)
```

This is a common Java pattern.  In Kotlin, it would be easier to drop the interface and just pass a function variable, but given you showed an `override` above, seems possible your view is coming from Java. Regardless, the key is to create an observable and have it create and set listener that calls `onNext`.

```
Observable.create(Observable.OnSubscribe<Int> {
        subscriber ->
        slider.setSlideListener(object : SliderChangedListener {
            override fun onSliderChanged(percent: Int) {
                subscriber.onNext(percent)
            }
        })
    }).subscribe { /* respond to the slide */ }
```

**Case 2: You extend the `Slider` class and override the listener**

In this case, I assume you have a listener method in your `Slider` class that you override directly with the code in your question.  In this case, we can use a `Subject` to mediate between the listener and the subscriber.

```
val mySlider = object : Slider() {
        val sliderObservable: PublishSubject<Int> = PublishSubject.create()
        override fun onSliderChanged(percent: Int) {
            sliderObservable.onNext(percent)
        }
    }
mySlider.sliderObservable.subscribe({ /* do slider work */ })
```

Comment: That's perfect. Case 1 was what I needed. I was trying to do Observable.create { } with the logic there instead of using the Observable.OnSubscribe<Int>